# Indentation issue

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if my indentation for this file is correct or not because my result that I got is not  aline together (not straight).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript for Loop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
        <script type = "text/javascript" >
            let x = 5;
        do {
            document.write("do while Looping " + x + "\n");
            x++;
        } while (x < 10)
        
        </script>      
        </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the text between the `<pre>` and the `<script>`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript for Loop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre><script type = "text/javascript" >
            let x = 5;
        do {
            document.write("do while Looping " + x + "\n");
            x++;
        } while (x < 10)
        
        </script>      
        </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, even better, avoid `document.write` entirely:

```js
let text = '';

let x = 5;
do {
  text += "do while Looping " + x + "\n";
  x++;
} while (x < 10)
document.querySelector('pre').textContent = text;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```